# tcpdump doesn't capture WiFi-to-WiFi traffic

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bridge, tcpdump, hostapd

I have configured a transparent bridge on a network that should capture all the traffic of its connected devices with tcpdump (see diagram [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLjHX.png)).

The bridge is configured on a Debian 11 server and has an uplink (eth1) to the router which also handles DHCP, etc.. Ethernet/LAN devices are connected via a network-HUB (not shown in the diagram) on eth2. Wi-Fi devices are connected via a USB 3.0 NIC (ALFA AWUS1900) by using hostapd (wlan0).
All the interfaces (eth1, eth2, wlan0) are configured as a bridge (br0).

When I try to capture PING-Traffic from different devices with

```
tcpdump -i br0
```

I can see the requests and responses from WLAN<->Internet, LAN<->Internet and LAN<->LAN.
However when I try to ping from one WLAN device to another WLAN device (for example from 192.168.0.21 to 192.168.0.22) the traffic doesn't get captured by tcpdump even though I get responses for the ping. Furthermore absolutely no traffic gets captured from one WLAN device to another.

Here is the relevant snipped of my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# Bridge interface
iface eth1 inet manual
iface eth2 inet manual
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth1 eth2
```

My /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
# INTERFACE CONFIGURATION
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
bridge=br0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

# WI-FI CONFIGURATION
ssid=****
hw_mode=g
country_code=AT
channel=1
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
# WPA
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=****
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

What am I missing here that WLAN to WLAN traffic doesn't get captured?
Any help would be really appreciated!

**Edit:**
Here is the output of `ip -a address`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp25s0f0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:6e:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ca:a0:96:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you edit your Question to also provide the output of `sudo ifconfig -a` while you have everything set up in the way you think should work?

Comment: @Spiff as I have no `ifconfig` on the server I used `ip -a address` and put the output in the question.

Comment: Isn't Wifi internal traffic directly routed on ARP level so it is never recognized by the `br0` interface?

Comment: @Robert: `br0`, a bridge, *is* an "ARP-level" interface. With e.g. several Ethernet ports bridged together using br0, tcpdump would show all traffic that's being forwarded at L2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`ap_isolate=1` in hostapd's settings](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/hostapd/hostapd.conf?h=hostap_2_10#n539) to prevent the Wireless driver to perform low-level bridging of the wireless frames coming from Wifi and sent back to same Wifi which short-circuits the network stack and the bridge `br0`.

But `ap_isolate` alone results in Wifi client isolation: it can't see anymore other Wifi clients without additional settings.

Wii-to-Wifi goes from:

```
wlan0 -----> AP -----> wlan0
             X

            br0
```

to (nowhere, or useless broadcasts the the Ethernet ports: loss of connectivity):

```
wlan0 ---> (AP) ---> br0 X
```

As a bridge never sends back traffic to the port it came from by default, Wifi-to-Wifi connectivity is disabled (that's why the parameter is called `ap_isolate` in the first place). This kind of traffic must be enabled back on the bridge for this case: [hairpinning](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge.8#hairpin)

```
bridge link set dev wlan0 hairpin on
```

(alternative command for exactly the same result: `ip link set dev wlan0 type bridge_slave hairpin on`)

Now traffic becomes:

```
wlan0 ---> (AP) --->
                    br0
wlan0 <--- (AP) <---
```

As switched traffic goes through `br0` because of `ap_isolate=1`, without disruption thanks to hairpinning, `tcpdump` will now be able to capture Wifi-to-Wifi on `br0` (or directly on the `wlan0` port).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This looks really promising. However when I add `ap_isolate=1` to my hostapd.conf and restart hostapd-service (or even reboot) I can still ping WLAN-WLAN devices (without hairpinning). Do you have any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: I found out that the driver I was using for my WiFi adapter wasn't able to handle `ap_isolate`. Trying another WiFi interface and driver, your solution works! Thank you very much.